# Caching functions - fwrite vs memcache

Tags: php, cache, optimization, memcache

Which will be faster and best option? Page will load faster with fwrite or memcached cached function? I need to store some functions in cache, they will not update very often, so need only to read it. Which one will be best option?

Comment: Not very clear what you are referring to here, or what language.  Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Updated topic - php language. What details? If i store data with fwrite in .txt file, or i store data in memcache, which one will be better and why?

Answer (score 1):

Memcache, by about 1000x

Memcached works by storing objects in RAM, if you were to fwrite the data it would be stored on a disk so you'd get disk performance. If possible, always go for Memcached over disk/file storage and make sure you change your memcached config to use a decent amount of ram (By default it'll only use 1GB so if you've got a decent server you can upgrade it a bit, I wouldn't give it more than 75% of your ram but a good chunk).